# disable past date after first date is selected datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

i'm working to make a simple booking form that redirect to an staah booking engine using GET (they dont have any apis or embedded widget).

the booking engine only accept "dd M yyyy" date format (eg 19 Apr 2018)

i have search SO but dont find any working solution, recently i found working fiddle and i have edit that fiddle for my need (you would know what i want to achieve in the fiddle). you can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/k5zookLt/1929/
but the problem is they have a different approach on the HTML code and i have tried to modifying the js code for my html but it doesn't work. i dont have any skill in javascript. i dont know why this fiddle doesn't work in my html code

my code

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
<div class="input-group date" >
<input type="text" class="jaraksmall sm-form-control form-control from " id="from" name="from" required>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
<div class="input-group date"> 
<input type="text" class="jaraksmall sm-form-control form-control to" id="to" name="to" required>
</div>
```

fiddle html code :

```
<div class="line col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label>First check in:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-1 input-sm"placeholder="CheckIn" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>First check out:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 input-sm" placeholder="CheckOut">
</div>
</div><!--line-->
```

how to make the js code from fiddle working well in my html code?
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because selector for `.each` and selector to find input element is not finding the required element. You need to :

1) to remove each statement.

2) modify datepicker input element selectors to use classes that you have added(to and from).

```
var startDate = new Date();
var fechaFin = new Date();
var FromEndDate = new Date(); 
var ToEndDate = new Date();

$(".from").datepicker({
autoclose: true,
startDate: "+0d",
format: 'd M yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf()))+1);
    $('.to').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
}); 

$('.to').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
format: 'd M yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('.from').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ronu0oym/)**

Comment: my form is horizontal, i've tested your answer but wrapping the column with another div make my input broken (be vertical) or simply ugly . any advice to avoiding using div or each in the js ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the html code as below

```
<div class="line" style="width:100%">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3" style="display: inline-block">
<div class="input-group date" >
<input type="text" class="jaraksmall sm-form-control form-control-1 form-control from " id="from" name="from" required>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3" style="display: inline-block">
<div class="input-group date"> 
<input type="text" class="jaraksmall sm-form-control form-control-2 form-control to" id="to" name="to" required>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddledemo](https://jsfiddle.net/k5zookLt/1962/)

Comment: my form is horizontal, i've tested your answer but wrapping the column with another div make my input broken (be vertical) or simply ugly . any advice to avoiding using div or each in the js ?